# Pause in AnimatorSet played sequentially

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I need to apply the following animation to an imageView:

```
1. alpha (0 -> 1) and scale (0 -> 1) in 500ms
2. pause for 1000ms
3. alpha (1 -> 0) and scale (1 -> 0) in 500ms
```

In my mind these are three `Animator`s which may be played sequentially with an `AnimatorSet`.

I wrote this code, in which the three blocks have been clearly separated:

```
ObjectAnimator alpha1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f);
ObjectAnimator scaleX1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_X, 0f, 1f);
ObjectAnimator scaleY1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_Y, 0f, 1f);
AnimatorSet part1 = new AnimatorSet();
part1.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
part1.setDuration(500);
part1.playTogether(alpha1, scaleX1, scaleY1);

ObjectAnimator pause = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.ALPHA, 1f);
pause.setDuration(1000);

ObjectAnimator alpha0 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f);
ObjectAnimator scaleX0 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_X, 1f, 0f);
ObjectAnimator scaleY0 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_Y, 1f, 0f);
AnimatorSet part2 = new AnimatorSet();
part2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
part2.setDuration(500);
part2.playTogether(alpha0, scaleX0, scaleY0);
```

In my opinion this code is clear, and better than having timers or listeners.
The main question is, **is there a kind of "`PauseAnimator`"** which may be used in similar situations? (actually the second block of code does nothing, it animates alpha from 1 to 1 in 1000ms)

Answer (score 3):

`setStartDelay()` method can be used for this purpose. Also, `PropertyValuesHolder` can be used to animate different properties of a view simultaneously.

Here are the steps at a high level:

1. Set up objectAnimator1 to animate raising alpha and upscaling x and y in parallel
2. Set up objectAnimator2 to animate in parallel lowering alpha and downscaling x and y with a start delay
3. Use AnimatorSet to animate objectAnimator1 and objectAnimator2 in a sequence.

Here is the Code: My view here is a text view named "mTextView"

```
// objectAnimator1 stuff
PropertyValuesHolder pvhToRaiseAlpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 0f, 1.0f);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhForxUpscale = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0f, 1.0f);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhForyUpscale = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0f, 1.0f);
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(mTextView, pvhToRaiseAlpha, pvhForxUpscale, pvhForyUpscale);
objectAnimator1.setDuration(500);

// objectAnimator2 stuff
PropertyValuesHolder pvhToLowerAlpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 1.0f, 0f);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhForxDownscale = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.0f, 0f);
PropertyValuesHolder pvhForyDownscale = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.0f, 0f);
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(mTextView, pvhToLowerAlpha, pvhForxDownscale, pvhForyDownscale);
objectAnimator2.setDuration(500);
objectAnimator2.setStartDelay(1000);

// AnimatorSet stuff
AnimatorSet sequenceAnimator = new AnimatorSet();
sequenceAnimator.playSequentially(objectAnimator1, objectAnimator2);
sequenceAnimator.start();
```

Comment: The problem is not the animation itself, but to pause it between two phases for a specified time